# Element content coming twice in the output xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I tried one code in the XSLT, it coming correctly only in the output. But coming as twice,

XML Input file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic
  PUBLIC "urn:pubid:com.saffron.doctypes:doctypes:dita:topic" "topic.dtd">
<topic>
      <title class="- topic/title " outputclass="MLU">Non-Insulin Injections: Up Close and
        Personal</title>
<body>
        <p class="- topic/p " outputclass="MLU_Code">W3333</p>
        <p class="- topic/p " outputclass="MLU_Condition">Injections</p>
        <p class="- topic/p " outputclass="MLU_Type">Select &amp; Reflect</p>
</body>
</topic>
```

XSL I used:

```
<xsl:template match="title[@outputclass='MLU'] | p[@outputclass='MLU_Code']">


    <trackingSettings>
    <urlcode>
    <xsl:value-of select="//p[@outputclass='MLU_Code']"/>
    </urlcode>
    <apiurl>http://mlucenter.com/like/api</apiurl>
    </trackingSettings>
    <page></page>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="p[@outputclass='MLU_Code']"/>
    <banner>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <text>       
    <xsl:value-of select="//title[@outputclass='MLU']"/>
    </text></banner>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="title[@outputclass='MLU']"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

Getting ouput is:

```
    <trackingSettings><urlcode>W3333</urlcode><apiurl>http://mlucenter.com/like/api</apiurl></trackingSettings>
<page/>
<banner><enabled>true</enabled>
<text>Non-Insulin Injections: Up Close and Personal</text></banner>
    <trackingSettings><urlcode>W3333</urlcode><apiurl>http://mlucenter.com/like/api</apiurl></trackingSettings>
<page/>
<banner><enabled>true</enabled>
<text>Non-Insulin Injections: Up Close and Personal</text></banner

>
```

I need the output element come at once. Please guide on that XSLT code. Thanks

Comment: provide your input XML

Comment: I edited @TechBreak. Please look into this

Comment: I would need well formed and valid xml

Comment: Please see now @TechBreak

Comment: I added suggestion, your template executes twice for each condition forcing to add content twice. Accept answer if found helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your OR '|' condition force to run things twice.

> xsl:template match="title[@outputclass='MLU'] |
>   p[@outputclass='MLU_Code']">

It is always better and recommended to have separation of concerns.

You need to match first by /topic (root) to get going and then invoke separate template .

```
<xsl:template match="/topic">
    <!-- invoke your separate templates-->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I can't upvote. Its saying 15 reputation needs for that

Comment: @BoopathyS you should accept answer as its your question